# How to run JavaFX on Hackintosh

Tags: javafx-2, java-7, hackintosh

I have created an application in JavaFx and deployed it. It runs perfectly in Mac and Windows system, but not in Hackintosh system.

When I start the application, it shows me "`JAVAFX Application quit unexpectedly`" message.

I guess this happens with every java application in Hackintosh system.

I need to run javafx in hackintosh also, Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Could you tell us which java version you're using?

Comment: There are some other people reporting on SO and elsewhere about this problem. I've been looking for a solution too, but so far I haven't found any hint. I have logged an issue: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28144.